# How to highlight points of multi series in same X value when mouse moves using highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

Considering this [official demo](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-basic). When my mouse moves to somewhere on x axis, a point in one of four series becomes highlight.

How to highlight points in same x value for all series when mouse move?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need the "shared" option in the tooltip, i.e.,

```
tooltip: { shared: true }
```

Example

http://jsfiddle.net/bv05y6Lg/

Comment: Thank you. This is what I want.